# TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Python and Django, and I modified this code from a tutorial. I'm getting `TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` when I load the page.  I've been troubleshooting and googling and can't seem to figure it out.  What am I doing wrong?

```
def report(request):
    flashcard_list = []
    for flashcard in Flashcard.objects.all():
        flashcard_dict = {}
        flashcard_dict['list_object'] = flashcard_list
        flashcard_dict['words_count'] = flashcard_list.count()
        flashcard_dict['words_known'] = flashcard_list.filter(known=Yes).count()
        flashcard_dict['percent_known'] = int(float(flashcard_dict['words_known']) /    flashcard_dict['words_count'] * 100)
        flashcard_list.append(flashcard_dict)
    return render_to_response('report.html', { 'flashcard_list': flashcard_list })
```

Comment: If any of these answers have helped please upvote and please accept the one that helps you the most.

Answer (score 28):

`count` requires an argument. It returns the number of instances of a particular item in a list.

```
>>> l = range(10) + range(10)
>>> l.count(5)
2
```

`2` here is the number of `5`s in the list. If you want the length of a list, use `len`.

```
>>> len(l)
20
```

Answer (score 11):

`count()` finds the number of times an item occurs in a list and hence needs that item as an argument. I think your looking for the number of items in a list. For this use `len()` not `count()`

```
flashcard_dict['words_count'] = len(flashcard_list)
flashcard_dict['words_known'] = len(flashcard_list.filter(known=Yes))
```

An example of `count()` would be

```
flashcard_dict['dog_count'] =flashcard_list.count('dog')
```

Answer (score 7):

It's not really clear what you are trying to do here. `flashcard_list` is an (empty) list, which you define before your loop. It doesn't make sense to call Django queryset functions like `count` and `filter` on it (there is a list method named count, but as the error says, it takes an argument, and counts the number of times that argument is found in the list).

Did you mean to use `flashcard.count()` instead? That still doesn't make sense, because flashcard is a single Flashcard instance, not a queryset. You'll need to explain a bit more exactly what you're hoping to do.

**Edit after comment** Right, so I think the issue is that you're trying to do all this inside a loop that iterates through each Flashcard, for some reason. In fact, I don't think you want the loop at all. Something like this would be better:

```
def report(request):
    flashcard_dict = {}
    flashcards = Flashcard.objects.all():
    flashcard_dict['list_object'] = flashcards
    flashcard_dict['words_count'] = flashcards.count()
    flashcard_dict['words_known'] = flashcards.filter(known=True).count()
    flashcard_dict['percent_known'] = int(float(flashcard_dict['words_known']) /    flashcard_dict['words_count'] * 100)
    return render_to_response('report.html', flashcard_dict)
```

Here you can see that you're operating on the queryset of all flashcards, rather than an empty list. And you're building up a single dictionary, not a list of dictionaries, and that dictionary itself becomes the template context - so in the template you can reference `{{ words_count }}` etc.

Comment: Sorry, I think you're helping me get on the right track. The whole point is to get the total number of flashcards and the total number of flashcards that are marked as "known" so I can get a percentage known of the total.

Answer (score 3):

The `count` method of a list counts the amount of times that `x` appears on the list. Check out the doc [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

If you want to know the amount of items in the list you need to use `len()`

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> print len(a)
3
```

Answer (score 2):

The `count` method is not quite what you're looking for.  On Python lists, `list.count(x)` tells you how many occurrences of `x` are in `list`.  You want `len(flashcard_list)`.  The function `len` is a built-in function that will tell you the length of a number of Python object types.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some argument to [count(x)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

> It returns the number of times x appears in the list.

```
>>> mylist  = [1,2,3,2]
>>> mylist.count(2)
2
>>> mylist.count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
>>>
```

It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve your `flashcard_list` list is empty. So before calling `count` on it you need to add something to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
alist = []
alist.append('a')
alist.count('a')
1
```

This would count all the 'a' in your list.